# Pythonic way to recalculate feature extent in ArcGIS 10.2

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, enterprise-geodatabase, extents

I am creating a tool that will automate a tedious process of data standardization. One of the steps is to recalculate the feature extent of a SDE file. Surprisingly I cannot find anything useful in regards to recalculating feature extent, except for a VBA script here: [Recalculating full extent of File Geodatabase feature class?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/24590/recalculating-full-extent-of-file-geodatabase-feature-class) and a tool here: http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=576ebff497094274bdd7c76e456de6c3. Unfortunately I don't know VBA well enough to understand fully what is going on or how to incorporate it into my existing Python script, nor do I know how to call an add-in. Also I will not be the only one using this tool and I'd rather avoid making everyone who uses the tool download the add-in. I've heard about reboxing but it doesn't seem like it's used anymore. Does anyone have any ideas on what I could do or how to use the VBA script in my Python script?

Comment: If [this answer](http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/116000) works it sounds like by far the easiest way to do this.

Comment: I read something before that said if you compacted the database, it would recalculate the extents.  I cannot confirm nor deny it, but I thought it could be something you look into.

Comment: @Branco That may have come from [another answer on the same question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/24595).

Comment: Compacting is actually the chosen answer for that question Branco. I'm not sure if I can do compression unless I can apply it to just one dataset. Polygeo, did you mean that the manual way of calculating extent (right click, properties, spatial extent, recalculate) as your suggested answer? I want to programmatically do this. Recalculating the extent is one step in a longer process of standardizing a dataset.

Answer (score 3):

Like in the comment of PolyGeo, [Compacting database recalculates feature class extent](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/24595/2969), so here is an arcpy script to automate this task and also to make rebuild index and analyze:

```
import arcpy , sys , os , subprocess
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

def main():

    db_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "Connection_db_name.sde")
    arcpy.env.workspace = db_path

    #disconnect all users from the database.
    arcpy.DisconnectUser(db_path, "ALL")

    # Run the compress tool.
    arcpy.Compress_management(db_path)

    #Allow the database to begin accepting connections again
    arcpy.AcceptConnections(db_path, True)


    # Get a list of all the datasets the user has access to.
    # First, get all the stand alone tables, feature classes and rasters.
    dataList = arcpy.ListTables() + arcpy.ListFeatureClasses() + arcpy.ListRasters()

    # Next, for feature datasets get all of the featureclasses
    # from the list and add them to the master list.
    for dataset in arcpy.ListDatasets():
        dataList += arcpy.ListFeatureClasses(feature_dataset=dataset)


    # pass in the list of datasets owned by the admin to the rebuild indexes and analyze datasets tools
    # Note: to use the "SYSTEM" option the user must be an administrator.
    arcpy.RebuildIndexes_management(db_path, "SYSTEM", dataList, "ALL")

    arcpy.AnalyzeDatasets_management(db_path, "SYSTEM", dataList, "ANALYZE_BASE", "ANALYZE_DELTA", "ANALYZE_ARCHIVE")

    ##this feature class if not deleted may cause some problems in the next compress
    arcpy.Delete_management(db_name+".sde.sde_compress_log")
```

[Geodatabase compression](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00170000000p000000) requires disconnecting all the users because `When the Compress tool is executed, the geodatabase is unavailable until compression is completed`

Comment: I can't disconnect all of the users from the database while this is going on, there are too many people using it. The process will be used one dataset at a time because not all of the data in the SDE are ready to be standardized so I want the compression to only apply to the dataset given in the initial parameters.

Comment: in documentation of geodatabase compression they say `When the Compress tool is executed, the geodatabase is unavailable until compression is completed`

Answer (score 3):

Avoid doing compress in geodatabase, that is not really want you want to accomplish.

If you are targeting ArcSDE file all you have to do is invoke
`sdelayer -o alter -E calc or sdelayer -o alter -E minx,miny,maxx,maxy`
from Python using the subprocess module.

You can recalculate the extent of your table by using SQL CTE like this

```
with
  cte_envelope as
  (
    select geom.STEnvelope() as envelope from MyTable
  ),
  cte_corner as
  (
    select envelope.STPointN(1) as point from cte_envelope
    union all
    select envelope.STPointN(3) from cte_envelope
  )
select min(point.STX) as min_x, min(point.STY) as min_y, max(point.STX) as max_x, max(point.STY) as max_y
from cte_corner
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a 'Basic' licence, try:

A simple way to recalculate feature extent in the event you have removed spatial features and are trying to zoom to the new extent is to move data into a GDB '**Feature Dataset**'.
On import the recalculation is performed, so when you 'zoom to layer' it zooms to the new extent of the feature class.  I did it this way as the compress method did not work for me.