# Edit xy domain of feature classes during import from boilerplate geodatabase schema (ArcGIS)

Tags: arcgis-desktop, esri-geodatabase, import, domains, xy

Situation:

I work for a company that creates geodatabases for a client that are restricted to a specific boilerplate schema (eg domains, subtypes, etc.).  During a recent draft review, the client complained that when zooming to full extent during an ArcMap session, the full extent was too far "out."

Desired solution:

Alter xy domain of empty feature classes (contained in feature datasets) to extent of interest area as they are imported into production geodatabase (I know that a feature dataset destination will ignore the xy domain environment setting).

Problem:

No geoprocessing tool (eg feature class-to feature class, import to geodatabase, project, define projection, etc.) will accomplish the task (inside or outside feature datasets).  The domain environment setting (advanced geodatabase) is ignored for all actions I've tried.

Comment: the XY domain is set in the IGeometryDef interface when the feature class is being created. You could try to set the Output Extent but that wont change the domain which is huge by default (for good reason). Have a read of http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/24590/recalculating-full-extent-of-file-geodatabase-feature-class which doesn't change the domain but the 'used extent'.

Comment: Thanks for the link... I think I'll try the ArcCatalog recalculate extent method mentioned in this thread.

I curious how this will affect inclusion into a feature dataset.  My understanding is that feature datasets enforce both spatial reference and extent?

Answer (score 0):

You can set up spatial bookmarks. This will allow them to view the data at the exact zoom and location that they want.

This should help: http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00660000043s000000

Comment: Thanks, my understanding is that bookmarks are a  map property... I need a solution that embeds into the geodatabase. Please let me know if I'm mistaken.