# Expanding extent of file geodatabase feature class in ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: extents, feature-class, arcgis-pro

An [answer by @CurtisPrice](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/189113/115) to [Recalculating full extent of File Geodatabase feature class?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/24590) alerted me to the Recalculate Feature Class Extent in [ArcGIS Desktop](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/recalculate-feature-class-extent.htm) which is also available in [ArcGIS Pro](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/recalculate-feature-class-extent.htm).

Using ArcGIS Pro 1.4.1, and a file geodatabase feature class, I would like to be able to do something similar to this tool, which reduces the feature class extent, but in my case I would like to increase the feature class extent.

The reason I want to do this is because while using ArcPy to move point features via arcpy.da.UpdateCursor and their SHAPE@XY tokens I am triggering this error:

> RuntimeError: The coordinates or measures are out of bounds.

This is because the location that I am moving the point to is not only west of its original location but also west of any other points in the feature class.

Is there a tool which can be used to expand the extent of a feature class?

If there is not, a workaround that I will try will be to create a feature class of four points that are all outside of the current extent, Append them into the feature class to hopefully trigger an update of its extent, do my point movements, and then Select all but those four points out into a new moved feature class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried my planned workaround of:

> create a feature class of four points that are all outside of the
>   current extent, Append them into the feature class to hopefully
>   trigger an update of its extent, do my point movements, and then
>   Select all but those four points out into a new moved feature class.

but it *seemed* to get blocked by a similar issue of trying to append outside the extent.  This was not tested thoroughly because I moved onto what thought was a better idea.

The solution I found was to:

1. Create an empty feature class (points)
2. Add fields to match the schema of the original
3. Use simultaneous search and insert cursors to read each point (row), move it west, and then insert it into the new feature class.